# How to use aruba_command with expect directive?

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

```
          commands:
            - expect:
                command: "vsx update-software ....."
                responses:
                  'The.....(y/n)?': 'y'
                  'Do.....(y/n)?': 'y'
```

I'm trying to run this on a Playbook, I'm getting this error:

```
"msg": "invalid keys: expect"
```

Comment: You appear to have conflated two differently named "command" concepts: the [`aruba_command:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/aruba_command_module.html#examples) only sends **aruba** commands to the device, it does not run a copy of `expect` against the connection; the [`expect:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/expect_module.html) module runs **shell** commands

Comment: I'm using the **expect** directive to confirm the execution of the command as it requires a "y" confirmation. Is there an alternative way to confirm the execution of the command or to bypass it ?

Comment: the [`auto-confirm`](https://techhub.hpe.com/eginfolib/Aruba/OS-CX_10.02/5200-5314/index.html#GUID-2AF0CBC8-A479-4E25-8218-00E0900B2E51.html) option appears to be what you'd want

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was what I'm looking for, appreciate it.